# C# .First() vs [0]

Tags: c#, performance, linq, collections

Interested, does approaches has any differences. 
 
So, I created two snippets.

```
Snippet A 
List<int> a = new List<int>();
a.Add(4);
a.Add(6);
int b = a.First();
```

and

```
Snippet B 
List<int> a = new List<int>();
a.Add(4);
a.Add(6);
int b = a[0];
```

In IL we trust, so

```
Snippet A IL
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0009:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.Add
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.Add
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0018:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.First
IL_001D:  stloc.1     // b
IL_001E:  ret
```

and

```
Snippet B IL
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0009:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.Add
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.Add
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0019:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.get_Item
IL_001E:  stloc.1     // b
IL_001F:  ret
```

Snippet B produced one command more IL, but which approach faster in the end?

Comment: I personally prefers using `First()` as it is more readable.

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Nice advice. I'll find ways to race them.

Comment: An would a tiny difference in speed ever matter in a real program?

Comment: They're different things. Not all collections have an indexer.

Comment: For a `List<T>`, using the indexer will be faster since the call to `First()` will in the end just use the indexer anyway, but it will do more checks along the way. Will it be much faster? No.

Comment: `First()` will check the type of its parameter, then tries to cast it to `IList<T>` and then calls list[0]. So it performs 2 extra steps, but you're probably not going to notice any difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could check it by yourself :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<long> resultsFirst = new List<long>();
        List<long> resultsIndex = new List<long>();

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
        {
            List<int>[] lists = new List<int>[10000];

            int temp = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
                lists[i] = new List<int>() { 4, 6 };                

            s.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
                temp = lists[i].First();

            s.Stop();

            resultsFirst.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);

            s.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
                temp = lists[i][0];

            s.Stop();

            resultsIndex.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("LINQ First()  :   " + resultsFirst.Average());
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("By index      :   " + resultsIndex.Average());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output in Release mode :

**LINQ First()   : 367**

**By index       : 84**

Output in debug mode :

**LINQ First()   : 401**

**By index       : 177**

P.S.

The source code for method First is:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            return list[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The casting operation `source as IList<TSource>` or creating an Enumerator object is very likely the reason why `First()` is considerably slower.

P.S.

With that in mind I wouldn't recommend always using indexer as it might produce a less readable code at times. Usually readability is more important than micro optimizations.

For example:

```
var lastEmployee = employees[employees.Count - 1]; // and even
var lastEmployee = employees[^1];                  // C#8
```

is less readable than:

```
var lastEmployee = employees.Last();
```

Comment: Doesn't first call to generic method `First<T>` will cause code generation at runtime?

Comment: You should precise to run it in release mode ;)

Comment: Is it me or not all paths return a value? I guess Jakub's code is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I did the test myself and yes, the difference is big! Every run, its different, but thats normal offcourse: LINQ First()  :   1633,62 By index      :   431,24. Another try: LINQ First()  :   1375,06 By index      :   375,82

Answer (score 6):

The [`Enumerable.First`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc8ae402a61dd9d6) method is defined as

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

So for a `List<T>` it ends up using the indexer after a null check and a cast. Seems not much, but when I tested the performance, `First` was 10x slower than the indexer (`for` loop, 10 000 000 iterations, release build: First - 100 ms, indexer - 10 ms).

Comment: It is not true for all existing framework versions, and it can be changed in future.

Comment: @astef Can you give an example of an existing framework version for which my answer is incorrect? I also cannot imagine any future changes in the framework that will make the results considerably different. The `Enumerable.First` is already optimized for `IList<T>`. The extra steps are necessary, I don't think they could be optimized away by JIT. The only thing that would change the results would be faster cast.

Comment: At minimum, all versions before 3.5. Even if you can't imagine how an implementation can change it is a good tone not to make assumptions about future and always specify an exact version of decompiled code

Comment: @astef There was no `Enumerable.First` before .NET 3.5, so how can we talk about its performance? I'm not making assumptions that nothing will change in the implementation. I am making an assumption that whatever changes are made, they will not considerably change the results. IMO it's safe to assume that when we have a specialized operation and a generic one, the specialized one will be faster (well, not slower - the generic one could be compiled/jitted to the specialized one)

Comment: @astef I ran the same test in .NET 3.5 - `Enumerable.First` was 20% slower than in 4.6. Does it make a difference when compared to the indexer? I don't think it does.

Answer (score 2):

In general, **concrete** class/interface methods should be favored over **generic** implementations because, well, the later are **generic** and the data structure is supposed to take its **specifics** into account. For instance, linked list should not provide indexer because it cannot be implemented efficiently. Ideally, every data structure will define a its own method with the same signature as the corresponding generic extension method when it can provide better implementation, and compiler will handle that properly. This can be treated as *specialization* and unfortunately is not supported very well as in C++ templates. The implementation of `Enumerable.First` is a good example of a "workaround" rather than a solution - it does optimization for a specific BCL interface, but cannot handle a custom data structure (like linked list) which can provide the same information much better than using the generic implementation. And it's even worse for the `Enumerable.Last`.

To resume, if you program against specific classes/interfaces, use their methods when possible. If you are programming against standard generic interfaces, well, you have no other options anyway (except defining your extension methods that shadow the standard ones, but that usually leads to clashes).

Answer (score 0):

Tested in LINQPad 5 with following code:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
  List<int> a = new List<int>();
  a.Add(i);
  a.Add(i+2);
  int b = a.First();//[0] for B
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

`.First()` gave 01:04.021 and 0:45.794 with optimization. 
`[0]` gave 0:44.288, 0:27.968 with optimization and better code for me, as I think.

Really, for me `[0]` is more readable than `.First()` and usually I don't need checks, provided by him. 
So, in most cases I'll choose `[0]`.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you're asking about asymptotic complexity, both approaches are `O(1)`, use any of it.

If you're asking about real speed, there's no answer, since it can differ from version to version, from one machine to another. IL you've generated is not the same for any other version of .NET.

Attempt to optimize your code by choosing one of these approaches is obviously premature optimization.

Comment: I do believe there is a speed difference, take a look at Fabjan's post and eat the pudding.

Comment: @Mark of course there's a difference. There's no way to execute the code two times without a difference. But my point is that the answer about practical speed of execution can not be given, strictly speaking. And if that's not a theoretical question, but a practical one, then it's a premature optimization and the right answer - don't do it.