# Performance difference between ArrayName.First() and ArrayName[0]

Tags: c#, linq

Given an array `ArrayEx`, are these two equivalent? As I am trying to map a complex object containing several arrays to my model, is there a difference in performance?

```
ArrayEx[0]
ArrayEx.First()
```

Comment: question is a near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165462/difference-between-list-first-list-elementat0-and-list0

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544269/c-sharp-first-vs-0

Comment: It is pretty hard to measure accurately, but count on First() to be about an order of magnitude slower than simple indexing.  That is *not* because First() is slow, it is because array indexing is so very, very fast.  Whatever you do next with the data you retrieved is pretty likely to make the difference unobservable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is an extension method for the `IEnumerable<T>` type which makes it more generic, where the first one is just a simple indexer.

`.First()` should be a bit slower.

Comment: Only a very tiny bit slower though. `First` checks if the source is an `IList`, and if so, just does `[0]`.

Comment: @hatchet true, it's almost a negligible performance difference.

Comment: @hatchet, indeed, but accessing an indexer through an interface (which implies a virtual method call) is significantly slower than accessing an array indexer (for which there's an IL instruction) directly. In most scenarios it doesn't really matter, but it matters for performance-critical code.